# Stackslider gallery not showing images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, gallery

I'm trying to create an image gallery like this:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/03/stackslider-a-fun-3d-image-slider/

I've been through the tutorial, but no images are appearing when I implement it into my site

http://saracook.coffeecup.com

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
<section id="portfolio_page">
<div class="container">
       <h2 class="page-title">Gallery</h2>   
       <ul id="st-stack" class="st-stack-raw">
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/1.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Graverobber</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/2.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Hideous Snake Queen</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/3.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Queen of Hearts</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/4.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dead Pirate vs Kraken</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/5.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Mountain Lion</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/6.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Flying Skull</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/7.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>The Fly &amp; Bureaucratic Elephant</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/8.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Failsnake</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/9.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Cultist</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/10.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Crusader &amp; Viking</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/11.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Crocodile</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/12.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Captain Banana</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="img/stack/13.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Werewolf</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
                <li><div class="st-item"><img src="iimg/stack/14.jpg" alt="image"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Vegetables</h2><h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3></div></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In wich part of your site?? Also if you can post some code or make a live example on http://jsfiddle.net will be great to explain in a bettter way your problem

Comment: It's supposed to be in the portfolio part of my site, i'll edit with html now

Comment: you get 404 error on those images

Comment: I think the images have not been uploaded

Comment: They open ok in my folder, how can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm still not seeing them, even though they are definitely uploaded into the site now

Comment: I see the images if remove de display none for the `ul id="st-stack"` but the slide isnt' working could be a big problem with the js and implementation ... have you tried make it work in a blank page? and after put it on your site

Comment: you need to add modernizer before stackslider and fix your demo.css

Comment: Sorry I don't have a demo.css anymore, so that shouldn't still be visible

Comment: your arrow navigation is working fine...but your bulleted nav is not working...is that the problem?

Comment: I've made those adjustments but I still can't see the images

Comment: I personally can't see any of the images, can everyone else?

Comment: Underneath the 'Gallery' title there should be a stack of images, like in the link I provided but for me, nothing is appearing. It's just 'Gallery' then my links to my social networks

Comment: the ul class="st-stack-raw" need the id="st-stack"

Comment: seems to be working now! the images are higher and further apart than they should be, but i'm sure i'll figure that out by playing with the css! thanks everyone